# How to put value from different fields using Python?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.4, fields-attributes

Here I added a new field name "visArea" and want to put in the number from the "Count" column which "Value" equals one.That means the number of visible point(value=1)from selected observe spot.I used embedded Python 2.7 within ArcGIS 10.4 and my code are:

```
fc="PythonVisi2.tif"
Cursor=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["Value","Count","visArea"])
for row in Cursor:
    if row[0] != 0:
    row[2]=row[1]
    cs3.updateRow(row[2])
```

But I got "TypeError: argument must be sequence of values".Which part goes wrong or how shold I fix the problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need "update" the complete row and use the name you have given the cursor so change `cs3.updateRow(row[2])` to `Cursor.updateRow(row)`.

Since you only have modified `row[2]` this is still the only value that will be updated.

Comment: Thank you.I tried and it works.But i don't get " the name you have given the cursor " since `Count`&`VisArea` is given as parameter in bracket.Do you mean i used `for row in cursor` rather than `for row[2] in cursor`?

Comment: @Joe.Z you name the cursor `Cursor` with this line: `Cursor=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["Value","Count","visArea"])`, so when you update it you need to use that name: `Cursor.updateRow(row)`

Comment: Indeed i neglected the name change.I actually want to ask since `row[2]` being the only value need updated, why does `Cursor.updateRow(row)` work while `(row[2])`doesn't ?

Comment: That is just the way the updatecursor works. You always need the complete row in updateRow

Comment: I totally understand.Thank you for the patience.  :) @BERA

Comment: Nice! @Joe.Z could you accept my answer with the checkbox?